# How to combine Workbook, Worksheet and Range variables into one Range, in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, range

Here is an example setting:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rn As Range
```

More specifically in my scenario:

The call:

```
Select Case CheckInDb(Range("Username"), "\..\_DataBase_\", "UserBase.xlsm", Sheets("UD_Base"), Range("UD_Base[U_ID]"))
```

The function header:

```
Function CheckInDb(What As Variant, Folder As String, FileName As String, Ws As Worksheet, Rn As Range)
```

I wanted to do something like this within the function (after opening the file, etc.):
(note: Wb is generated within the function)

```
CheckInDb = IsError(Application.Match(What,Wb.Ws.Rn, 0))
```

---

I have tried in several ways to precombine them step by step instead, but did not succeed with any
for example

```
set ws = wb.Sheets("RangeAdding")
```

would work manually, but **Ws=Wb.Ws** NOT. How to work around this, to achieve all 3 parts coming from variables?

### Adding more information

I will post my full function to show what the real issue is. I have modded it a bit according to your suggestions, and the problem is:

The Workbook only gets opened inside the function, however **if it is not open already when I write the full range in the calling it will give me an error**, that it does not exist. Therefore I wanted to first ever use the range "live" inside the function, when the reference is already open.

```
Sub checkUser()
    Select Case CheckInDb(Range("Username"), "\..\_DataBase_\", "UserBase.xlsm", Workbooks("Userbase.xlsm").Sheets("UD_Base").Range("UD_Base[U_ID]"))
        Case True: Range("Status_U").Value = ("Szabad")
        Case False: Range("Status_U").Value = ("Foglalt")
    End Select
End Sub
Function CheckInDb(What As Variant, Folder As String, FileName As String, Rng As Range)
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim wasOpen As Boolean
    Dim File As String, Path As String
    ' Relative path:
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & Folder
    File = Path & FileName

    On Error Resume Next
         Set Wb = Workbooks(FileName)
         wasOpen = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Wb Is Nothing Then
         Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(File, , True) 'with settings: (File, true,true,  , PW)
         wasOpen = False
    End If

    '...

 CheckInDb = IsError(Application.Match(What, Rng, 0))

    '...

    Select Case wasOpen
            Case True
                'Wb.Save
            Case False
                'Wb.Save
                Wb.Close (False)
    End Select

    Set Wb = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: So your question is simply how to pass the **name** of a workbook and the **name** of a worksheet within that workbook and the **name** of a range within that worksheet?

Comment: In fact yes, that would be enough. I have tried to pass it as TEXT only, but i did not manage to transorm it later into range, like range(TEXT) or something...   The funny thing is that i have a working solution without using the function, i just wanted to make it a function to be able to reuse the same call in multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rn` object already knows which `Worksheet` object it belongs to.  (You can use `rn.Parent` to refer to that worksheet.)  And the worksheet knows which `Workbook` object it belongs to.  (You can use `rn.Parent.Parent` to refer to that workbook.)

So your code should be:

```
CheckInDb = IsError(Application.Match(What, Rn, 0))
```

This means there is no need to pass the workbook and worksheet information to your function (because it is inherent in the `Range` you are passing), i.e.:

```
Select Case CheckInDb(Range("Username"), Range("UD_Base[U_ID]"))
```

and

```
Function CheckInDb(What As Variant, Rn As Range)
```

---

Based on your edit to the question, which now makes it clear that all the objects in the calling procedure don't exist when you execute the call (and therefore the call fails), you should pass the **names** of your workbook (as you already do), worksheet and range, i.e.:

```
Sub checkUser()
    Select Case CheckInDb(Range("Username"), _
                          "\..\_DataBase_\", "UserBase.xlsm", _
                          "UD_Base", _
                          "U_ID")
        Case True: Range("Status_U").Value = ("Szabad")
        Case False: Range("Status_U").Value = ("Foglalt")
    End Select
End Sub

Function CheckInDb(What As Variant, _
                   Folder As String, FileName As String, _
                   wsName As String,
                   rngName As String) As Boolean
    '...
    '... existing code to create wb object
    '...
    Dim rn As Range
    Set rn = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(rngName)
    CheckInDb = IsError(Application.Match(What, Rn, 0))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think it does not apply/help in my situation. I need to transfer the range somehow to the place where i really want to use it, and prevent it from being tested before.
I really hope , not "on error resume next" will be my solution.... :P

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki Hopefully the edit to the answer will show how to pass String variables to the function instead of non-existent object references.

Comment: prevent it from being tested = prevent VBA to try to analyse it. Since the workbook is nto yet open at that moment , VBA thinks that the range is invalid... but it will be valid by the time i need it.

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki Are you wanting those references to objects (i.e. to the worksheet and to the range) to be returned to the calling procedure?  Because if they don't exist before you invoke the function, and you don't need the references after you invoke the function, then there is no point in having them as parameters.

Comment: Oh YES, exactly...! :)  Thank you.   My mistake was when trying that approach is that I have tried to include the full expression as string, like "worsheets(""xyz"").Range("" xyz"")" and translate THAT somehow into a range... I dont know if that is possible (You can tell me for fun) , But your Solution is already working and excellent

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki You **could** pass something like `"worsheets(""xyz"").Range(""abc"")"` ... but you wouldn't be able to make use of it like that.  You would need parse that string to find the `"xyz"` and `"abc"` bits so that you could use those bits in the appropriate locations in your code.  Much easier just to pass the bits you are after rather than encoding it within a longer string.